# Jquery function not working from a dynamic load content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a problem trying to make this additemtolist fuction to work, the id=clickitemtoadd is a list loaded dynamicly with avalible items. but because is Dynamic load is not working.

Here is the code for `onclick` call a function:

```js
function additemtolist(pos_name,item_id,pos_value){
  alert('clicked')
}
```

```html
<p id="clickitemtoadd" onclick="additemtolist('item name','item id','item sales value')">item name</p>
```

Comment: Please create a [mre] that actually demonstrates your problem. The snippet you've posted works as intended. Furthermore why did you tag this with JQuery? It appears you're not using JQuery

Comment: <p id="clickitemtoadd" onclick="additemtolist('item name','item id','item sales value')">item name</p> is loaded dynamicly and this is the reason as why it des not work when onclick function is called

Comment: your code seems to be working fine.  : https://jsfiddle.net/kwnevzhc/1/ . I have added element dynamicaally

Comment: The problem is when you load content from a already dynami load content

Main code -> Dynamic load - Dynamic load -< here every thing stops working

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements) answer your question?

Comment: "*The problem is when you load content from a already dynamically loaded content*" - *predictably* this also works: https://jsfiddle.net/0jf8reaz/

Answer (score -1):

I found a work around solution for someone with this problem

Script:

```
<script>
$('#mainbody').on('click', '#clicitemtoadd', function(event) {
var $this = $(this);  // Cache the clicked element

if (!$this.data('processed')) {  // Check if it hasn't been processed yet
$this.data('processed', true);  // Mark it as processed
var dataitemid = $this.attr('data-item-id');
alert(dataitemid);
}
});
</script>
```

html:

```
<p id="clicitemtoadd" data-item-id="9999">9999</p>
```

Comment: This answer bears absolutely no resemblance to the question.   No-one would possible know that this is the solution given the question.

Comment: Its a workaroud not the solution.

Comment: @5ElementosSPA since you are the original poster of the question and since you got a workaround. you need to delete the question. As no one can know by reading the question how this workaround worked. Kindly delete the question.

Answer (score -2):

<strike>use [live](https://api.jquery.com/live/) instead of inline `onclick`.</strike>**deprecated**

Use Delegated event handlers :

```js
$(document).ready(()=>{
    $('#createBtn').on('click',()=>{
    $('<button id="actionBtn">Clickme</a>').appendTo('#ctn');
  });
  $('#ctn').on('click','#actionBtn',()=>{
    console.log('click');
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ctn">

</div>
<button id="createBtn">
CREATE
</button>
```

Comment: It's deprecated and removed as well. version deprecated: 1.7, removed: 1.9

Comment: sorry, i just notice it

Comment: There is no reason answering obviously duped questions anyway

Comment: This type of question is answered a lot of times over SO. So need to close as dupe, not to answer.

Comment: @DarkBee Given GregS11's relative new entry to the site, I would guess they've not yet seen that this question tends to get asked at least a few times every week (some days 4-5 times a day)  - doesn't excuse the `live` solution though ;)

Comment: (nor the obviously duplicated `id=`)